# Custom template doesn't accept shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a custom template by copying page.php and then removing basically everything except for the CSS link, so it looks like this:[image]

The div on line 20 just puts a red box on the page so I can recognize that this template, and the linked CSS file, are handling the page. (The idea is to create a large blank page where I can put large tables.  I don't want any header markup or sidebar markup, etc., to distract attention from the table.)

I see the red box fine, but when I try to insert a shortcode  on the page, to insert a table from TablePress,  the shortcode isn't processed.  I assume I removed something from page.php that is needed to process shortcodes, since a normal new page, that uses page.php, processes the shortcode fine. Does anyone know what I might have removed that killed the shortcodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts about your code / problem:

1) I think you should not insert the stylesheet link like this. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

2) You can insert the shortcode with

```
<?php
 echo do_shortcode('[ShortcodeName]');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I agree I should enque the style sheet but I just wanted something quick for now.  do_shortcode() does execute the TablePress shortcode but it doesn't put in the column sort functions. Apparently I'm still missing some JavaScript loads.